# Regular expression - Find the first link in a text

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm using the regular expression below to find the first link in a text. Currently this version numbers get misinterpreted as links:

```
ver.1.0
xx.11
v1.2
```

RegExp:

```
var findLink:RegExp = /([äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\-\:\/]{2,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)/g
var getLink = themessage.text.match(findLink)
trace(getLink[0])
```

Example text:

> Lorem Ipsum ver.1.0  is simply dummy text xx.11  of the printing v1.2
>   and typesetting industry. example.com (example.com should only be found as a link)

How can I add the condition to my RegExp that the characters after the second dot (if there is one at all) needs to be a-z and have a minimum of 2 characters? So that example.co or www.example.co works but example.1 or 1.example.a is not interpreted as a URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
var find:RegExp = / (https?\:\/\/[^ ]*)/g;
trace(myText.match(find));
```

The regular expression will look for

```
a whitespace
http
s but not necessarly
://
a bunch of characters that are not whitespaces
```

The ( ) are there to delimit which group of characters the RegExp should catch. The g parameters at the end tells the RegExp not to stop looking after the first match.

ADDENDUM

If you want to match an URL without http, this should work to get a word with at least one point inside:

```
/ ([a-z\:\/]+\.[a-z\.]+) /g
```

At least one character of lowercase alphabet, : and /
    A dot
    At least one character of lowercase alphabet and .

Comment: How can I add the condition to my RegExp that the characters after the second dot (if there is one at all) needs to be a-z and have a minimum of 2 characters? So that `example.co` or `www.example.co` works but `example.1` or  `1.example.a`  is not interpreted as a URL. Thanks!

Comment: The `+` quantifier is a shortcut for `{1,}` - so to have a minimum of two characters, change `+` to `{2,}` - however, be aware that you can have one character domain segments (e.g. `i.imgur.com`), and of course IP addresses can start and end with single digits.

Comment: Just looked closer at this answer, it wont match URLs such as `<http://google.com>` or `[markdown](http://whatever.com)`. The `:` doesn't need to be escaped in either regex, and the last regex will match completely non-url patterns like `://:..` whilst failing to match hyphenated URLS like `experts-exchange.com` - or again due to the space requirement (and it is a space - char 32 - not _any_ whitespace, a URL at the start of content or preceded/succeeded by a tab or newline.

Answer (score 0):

For just identifying a URL in a string, this seems to work well for me.

```
/([fh]t{1,2}ps?:\/\/)?[\w-]+\.\w{2,4}/
```

It identifies HTTPS, HTTP, and FTP URLs, as well as URLs that don't have any of those prefixed.

```
var string:String;
var istr:int;
istr = string.search(/([fh]t{1,2}ps?:\/\/)?[\w-]+\.\w{2,4}/);

trace(string.slice(istr).indexOf(" "));
```